# Selecting rows with max value, in correlation to two other columns

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, groupwise-maximum

I have a table with three columns: region, country, count.
I want to reduce my table to rows of region, country and count - where count is maximal among the region.

For example, if I have the following table:

```
region | country | count
asia   | jo      | 12
asia   | ir      | 12
asia   | il      | 10  
europe | fr      |  8
europe | it      |  2
```

I'd expect to get in return:

```
region | country | count
asia   | jo      | 12
asia   | ir      | 12
europe | fr      |  8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this in this way: First you need to group the data by the `region` field and get the maximum value. Then execute a simple `IN` condition with fields `region` and `count`

```
select * from my_table WHERE (region, count) in (select region, MAX(count) from my_table  GROUP BY region)
```

Demo in [sqldaddy.io](https://sqldaddy.io/b2770986)